# How can i specify the line colour using gplot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I would like to plot a graph in MATLAB using gplot.

In the documentation for gplot, it says the proper syntax is:

```
gplot(A,Coordinates,LineSpec)
```

so if I do something like:

```
gplot(A,XY,'-or');
```

it will plot the graph in red with circles for the vertices. My problem is that i would like to plot it in grey, however the documentation for LineSpec seems to only allow line colours in the set: {r,g,b,c,m,y,k,w}; i can't seem to find anywhere in the documentation that lets you specify the line colour using an RGB triplet.

Am i just missing something?

Comment: Didnt the example in my answer to your other question work?

Comment: 'gplot' works in such a werid way that I would totally avoid it and do it with plot calls.

Comment: as in iterate over the adjacency list and plot each vertex and edge one by one? wouldn't that be really inefficient?

Comment: if you type `edit gplot` you will see how `gplot` draws the stuff. Just copy that and then give `plot` whatever arguments you need for formating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the `gplot` code it's a bit strangely designed. It uses the standard `plot` function but the logic it uses to get the line spec precludes the use of PV pairs that work with `plot`. Other than modifying the code I don't see a way to specify the `Color` property with `gplot` like you can with a normal line plot.

However, there is undocumented behavior in `gplot` that will allow you to plot the data normally yourself using a standard `plot` call. From the code:

```
%   [X,Y] = GPLOT(A,xy) returns the NaN-punctuated vectors
%   X and Y without actually generating a plot. These vectors
%   can be used to generate the plot at a later time if desired.  As a
%   result, the two argument output case is only valid when xy is of type
%   single or double.
```

So we can get our `XY` data and plot ourselves:

```
k = 1:30;
[B,XY] = bucky;
[X, Y] = gplot(B(k,k),XY(k,:));
plot(X, Y, '-*', 'Color', [0 1 1]);
axis square
```

[image: yay]

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot for that.. i wonder why they didnt include the 'Color' parameter in gplot..

Comment: Indeed. I'm wondering many things about the way it's written.